# Is it possible to detect where the swipe happens in Net MAUI?

Tags: xaml, swipe, .net-maui

[image]

I'm writing a .Net MAUI application and am using SwipeGestureRecognizer. This is all working great. But what I can seem to find is if you can detect where the swipe occurred.

.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" >
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <SwipeGestureRecognizer  Direction="Right" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
   ...
```

.xaml.cs

```
private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

But I specifically want to detect if you swipe in from an edge, primarily so I can show a popout menu on the edge. I can see nothing in the event args (of the `Swiped` event that I could use to detect where the swipe happened.

Consider the image attached. How can I tell (or detect) the difference between the wholly on-screen swipe action (green) from the off-screen swipe action (red). Some location parameters would be perfect, but they don't seem to exist.

I can't see anything in the MAUI docs to suggest this is even possible

Does anyone know if there is any way to achieve this, please?

Thanks?

Comment: On which control are you using SwipeGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: I've tried it on a few controls, Grid and StackPanel mainly. Normal swipe works fine, but I want to detect a swipe in from any edge.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an elegant solution but you can place an invisible `BoxView` on the left:

```
<Grid>
        <BoxView
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="40"
            Color="Transparent">
            <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                    Direction="Right"
                    Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped"
                    Threshold="25" />
            </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
        </BoxView>

        <!-- your content -->
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15,0,0,0">
            <Button />
            <Label Text="label" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</Grid>
```

I have decreased the value of `Threshold` because the swipable distance is small.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I did think about doing that and agree it's not elegant as I'm planning to have both left and right-edge menus and both really want to clutter my XAML with elements just for this feature. I won't accept it as an answer just yet, let's see if anyone else comes up with a solution. I might suggest something on the MAUL forum.